# Android: TabHost - passing Parameters to Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, actionbarsherlock

I am working on a TabHost with a WebView inside of each Fragment.
What I do is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++){
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tabNames[i]).setIndicator(tabNames[i]),
                Web.class, null);
 }
```

How can I pass parameters to each Fragment. In this case I want to pass an URL to each Fragment inside the TabHost.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you get this? I need the same. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure. I think I implemented a static class which holds the data. Or something like that. Currently I am not working on this particular project anymore.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I get the solution. You can pass parameters using a Bundle in the last parameter of "addTab" where you have "null".

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++){
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.put...
        mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tabNames[i]).setIndicator(tabNames[i]),
                Web.class, b);
 }
```

And then in the Fragment you can get the Bundle with getArguments().

I hope it will be useful for someone in the future

Comment: but inside the fragment's `onCreateView()`, `getArguments()` always gives me `null`, do you know why?

Comment: Yo have to do it in the onCreate

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad, I forgot to pass it while instantiating the tab in my tabListener :)